# How is the link like `<script src="/rmarkdown-libs/jquery/jquery.min.js">` correct and hidden?

Tags: r, blogdown

In blogdown's documentation, the fourth paragraph of [Appendix D.5](https://bookdown.org/yihui/blogdown/dep-path.html), it says,

> The links on the published website will be correct and typically hidden from the readers of the pages.

Thought there is a footnote

> For example, a reader will not see the `<script>` tag on a page, so it does not really matter what its `src` attribute looks like as long as it is a path that actually exists.↩

I still don't understand how the link become correct and hidden.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just cannot see the content of `<script>` tags on an HTML page. Typically they function behind the scenes. For example, right here on this StackOverflow page, jQuery is used (`<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>`) but you cannot physically *see* it on the page, unless you take a look at the HTML source of this page. Sometimes JavaScript does create visual elements on a page, but again, the `<script>` tags themselves are not directly visible. The content of other tags like `<p>`, `<ul>`, and `<blockquote>`, and so on, are often visible on a page, such as the paragraph you are reading right now (`<p>`).

So I don't understand why you feel there is a contradiction between visibility and correctness. A `<script>` tag can be correct, and invisible on an HTML page.

Comment: Thanks for your generous explanation. I have been developing websites myself. So in my mind, the `<script>` tag and so on is physically on the page. When I read your documentation, I thought there were some functions which edit the `src` attribute to make it **correct** and some magic to let the `<script>` tag disappear in the html file but still function. Last but not least, sorry for wasting your time in explaining basic webpage knowledge. I should have made my question clearer.